# Can I install Homebrew after Xcode?

Tags: installation

The [Homebrew Installation Instructions](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation) list installing Xcode after running the [Ruby Homebrew install script](https://gist.github.com/raw/323731/install_homebrew.rb).

Does the order matter? I.e., is it OK if I run the script after I've installed Xcode?

I already have Xcode 4 installed.

I looked at the script and just ran it, and I don't think the order matters because all it did was create `/usr/local`, set its permissions and group, and install some files there:

```
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/Library/Formula/...
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/...

Press enter to continue

==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+w /usr/local
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/chgrp staff /usr/local
==> Downloading and Installing Homebrew...
==> Installation successful!
```

Would it make any difference if I reinstalled the same exact disk image (`.dmg`) of Xcode 4 now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely fine to install Xcode first. Note that the end of the script even checks if Xcode is installed and complains only if it isn't yet.